# How to seed Test db just once in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a large dictionary of 180,000 words that needs to be loaded into the database in order for my app to run and would be useful to test with.  Unfortunately, this takes around 30 minutes to seed the database with.  Is there anyway to seed the db just once, or to even seed just one table of the db and allowing other tables to be refreshed each run?

EDIT:  I ended up using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to greatly speed up the seeding process.  It now takes 16 seconds and not half an hour.  I also noticed that in my `/spec/rails_helper.rb` file I had the following:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
     Rails.application.load_seed # loading seeds
  end
```

I obviously had added it a long time ago and had forgotten about it since this is kind of a template rails_helper file I use.  Commenting that out meant I don't run it every time, and if I ever do need to reseed I could, just by uncommenting it.

For some reason I thought incorrectly that rspec just seeded by default, which is not the case.

Comment: 30 minutes seems excessive. Could you show your seeding code? What do you do with these 180,000 words?

Comment: I ended up using activerecord-import which cut this down to about 16 seconds.  Still too long for testing, but will help if I need to update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your seeding more efficient with the new Rails 6 [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all). This creates multiple records with a single `insert` and does not instantiate models. OTOH it doesn't do any validation, so be careful.

```
DictionaryWords.insert_all([
  { word: "foo" },
  { word: "bar" },
])
```

Alternatively, use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).

---

But it's better not to make 180,000 words at all.

The problem with seeds and fixtures is they're "one size fits all". They must encompass every possible dev and testing situation. They're fragile, one change to the seed might mysteriously break many tests which made assumptions about the fixtures. Seeds will be blown away if you need to reset your databases.

Instead, use a [factory](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) and create what you need when you need it. Use a library such as [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) to generate fake but valid data.

For example...

```
# Assuming you have classes called Dictionary and DictionaryWord
factory :dictionary do
end

factory :dictionary_word do
  dictionary
  word { Faker::Lorem.unique.word }
end
```

Then in your tests create words as you need. Here I'm using [RSpec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/).

```
let(:dictionary) { create(:dictionary) }
let!(:words) { create_list(:dictionary_word, 3, dictionary: dictionary) }

context 'when the word is in the dictionary' do
  let(:word) { words.sample }

  it 'finds the word' do
    expect( dictionary.exists?(word) ).to be_truthy
  end
end

context 'when the word is not in the dictionary' do
  let(:word) { "septemburary" }

  it 'does not find the word' do
    expect( dictionary.exists?(word) ).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

And if you need more words for manual testing, open a console and make some.

```
[1] pry(main)> FactoryBot.create_list(:dictionary_words, 100)
```

This is not particularly efficient, but you probably don't really need 180,000 words.

---

Comment: The app that I'm developing scrapes an external article and then creates links to words in the database, so I think it would be difficult to test without having the dictionary in place.  I guess I could just create words on demand though, or test with a dummy url that scans a local file.

Comment: @Mac Yes, you don't need the entire dictionary to do most of your testing. You also don't need a network connection. Your scraping method should work with a response, it should not do the fetching itself. Mock the method which does the page request to return generate test responses. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs You can have a handful of release tests which actually do a network connection and load the full dictionary.

Comment: I'll look into that.  Thanks for the help.  I'm building this out as demo / resume app, so it's best do things the 'proper' way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run just once.

1. first time you should run seed for the test env

   RAILS_ENV=test rails db:seed
2. Now run RSpec